# Find average on string field containing numbers in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have UserStat table with property and value defined as string...
When I do   select (CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'"
everything is fine :

UserStat.find_by_sql(" select (CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'")
  UserStat Load (8.6ms)   select (CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'

=> [#< UserStat id: nil, value: 869>]

but when I do:

UserStat.find_by_sql(" select AVG(CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'")

UserStat Load (9.7ms)   select AVG(CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'

=> [#< UserStat id: nil>]

where is my value field ???? I think I must get 869 as value ..

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem with 
   a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select AVG(CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'")
   a[0]['avg'].to_i

But stil think that 
UserStat.find_by_sql(" select AVG(CAST(value as integer) ) from user_stats where property = 'BEST_SCORE'") must raise error or return value..